# Is there a difference between "jamb" and "jam"?

Tags: differences, verbs, homonyms

Is there a difference between *jamb* and *jam*?

I recently wrote a letter describing someone who had jambed their hand on a stair bannister and the usage was questioned.

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? What in there didn't help?

Comment: Not sure how your sarcasm is supposed to contribute here. This question was marked as answered over six months ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Jamb" has a very specific meaning. From NOAD:

> **jamb** |jam|
>   *noun*
>   a side post or surface of a doorway, window, or fireplace.
>   • a columnar mass or pillar in a mine or quarry.

It is not used as a verb, except perhaps figuratively.

Comment: I am aware of the architectural meaning. Looking at OED it seems I am using a very obsolete form.

Comment: What form would that be? http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/100691?redirectedFrom=jamb#eid